# how do i update an html element with an item retrieved from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, frontend, local-storage

I have a code with an html span that has a content of 0.00 and I want to update this span with an item from localStorage
so I don't lose the data when reloading the page, I can rescue the item, but it disappears when I f5 on the page
Does anybody know how to solve this?

my html code:

I have a button that when clicked should update the span with the item saved in localStorage

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Products</title>
</head>
<body>
    

    <div>Products</div>
    <button><a href="/index.html">Products</a></button>
    <div data-js="value-cart-products">0,00</div>
    <button data-js="add-product">Add to Cart</button>

    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can rescue the item from localStorage, but when I reload the page the item is lost.

my javascript code:

```js
const addProducts = document.querySelector('[data-js="add-product"]')
const cartValue = document.querySelector('[data-js="value-cart-products"]')

let valueCartNumber = 1

let getNumber = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('number'))

let updateLocalStorage = ()=>{
    localStorage.setItem('number', JSON.stringify(valueCartNumber))
}

addProducts.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    cartValue.innerHTML = getNumber;
})
updateLocalStorage()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event when you refresh the page to check if something in localStorage exists. for example

```
if (localStorage.getItem(....)) {// update your variables here}
```

Comment: how exactly, could you explain better please?

Answer (score 0):

```
const addProducts = document.querySelector('[data-js="add-product"]');
const cartValue = document.querySelector('[data-js="value-cart-products"]');

const valueCartNumber = 1;

if (localStorage.getItem('number')) {
  cartValue.innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('number'));
}

const updateLocalStorage = () => {
  localStorage.setItem('number', JSON.stringify(valueCartNumber));
};

addProducts.addEventListener('click', () => {
  updateLocalStorage();
});
```

First you check if the value is stored in the localstorage. If it is you populate the cartValue html node.
On click you update the storage with the value contained in the constant valueCartNumber;

Answer (score 0):

There are two examples that load data from `localStorage` when the `"DOMContentLoaded"` event fires on `document` (Basically when page is done loading the DOM). **Example A** is a simple `<data>` and `<button>`. **Example B** is a more complex yet expandable setup involving `<form>`, `<input>`, `<output>`, and `<button>`.

**Note:** SO Snippets do not allow the WebStorage API to function so the console is disabled so the unnecessary errors logged won't clutter up the Snippet. Having said that, the Snippets will not work.

**Example A**

```js
/**
 * Saves data as a string to localStorage
 * @param {string} key - A name to reference the data by
 * @param {any<JSON>} data - Data to be saved as string. JSON restrictions apply
 */
const save = (key, data) => localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
/**
 * Loads data from localStorage as originally typed
 * @param {any} key - A name the data is referenced by
 * @returns {any} - The data converted from string to it's original type OR 0
 */
const load = key => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) || 0;

/**
 * Reference <data class="qty">
 * Reference <button class="add"> 
 */

const qty = document.querySelector(".qty");
const add = document.querySelector(".add");

/**
 * Bind "DOMContentLoaded" event to document
 * Assign the value retrieved by load() function to qty.value
 */
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  qty.value = load("total");
});

/**
 * Bind "click" event to <button>
 * When triggered invoke addItem(e) function
 */
add.addEventListener("click", addItem);

/**
 * Event handler passes the Event object by default
 * total is #qty value incremented by 1
 * If total is less than 0 #qty value is 0...
 * if total is more than 99 #qty value is 99...
 * otherwise it's just total.
 * Save the value of #qty to localStorage
 */
function addItem(e) {
  let total = +qty.value;
  total++;
  qty.value = total < 0 ? 0 : total > 99 ? 99 : total;
  save("total", qty.value);
}
```

```css
html {font: 300 2ch/1 "Segoe UI"}
data, button {display:block;line-height: normal}
button {font: inherit; height: 2rem; cursor: pointer;}
data {font-weight: 100; font-size: 1.5rem;font-family:Consolas}
data::before {content: attr(value);}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link href="lib/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <data class="qty"></data>
    <button class="add">Add to Cart</button>

    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Example B**

```js
/**
 * Saves data as a string to localStorage
 * @param {string} key - A name to reference the data by
 * @param {any<JSON>} data - Data to be saved as string. JSON restrictions apply
 */
const save = (key, data) => localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
/**
 * Loads data from localStorage as originally typed
 * @param {any} key - A name the data is referenced by
 * @returns {any} - The data converted from string to it's original type OR 0
 */
const load = key => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) || 0;

/**
 * Reference <form id="cart">
 * Reference to all form controls (<input>, <button>, output>)
 * Reference <input id="adj">
 * Reference <output id="qty"> 
 */
const cart = document.forms.cart;
const io = cart.elements;
const adj = io.adj;
const qty = io.qty;

/**
 * Bind "DOMContentLoaded" event to document
 * Assign the value retrieved by load() function to qty.value
 */
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  qty.value = load("quantity");
});

/**
 * Bind "submit" event to <form>
 * When triggered invoke addRemove(e) function
 */
cart.addEventListener("submit", addRemove);

/**
 * Event handler passes the Event object by default
 * Stop the <form> from sending data to a non-existant server
 * Reference the value of #adj
 * total is the sum of #qty value and #addRem value
 * If total is less than 0 #qty value is 0...
 * if total is more than 99 #qty value is 99...
 * otherwise it's just total.
 * Save the value of #qty to localStorage
 * Reset #adj value to 0 in order to avoid accidental double-clicks 
 */
function addRemove(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const adjustment = +adj.value;
  const total = +qty.value + adjustment;
  qty.value = total < 0 ? 0 : total > 99 ? 99 : total;
  save("quantity", qty.value);
  adj.value = 0;
}
```

```css
html {font: 300 2ch/1 "Segoe UI"}
form, label {display: inline-flex; align-items: center}
output, input, button {display:inline-block;line-height: normal}
input, button {font: inherit; height: 2rem;}
input, output {font-weight: 100; font-size: 1.5rem;font-family:Consolas}
input {width: 4rem;height: 1.65rem;text-align: center}
output {margin-right: 1rem}
button {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link href="lib/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="cart">
      <label>Quantity:&nbsp;<output id="qty"></output></label>
      <input id="adj" type="number" min="-99" max="99" value="0" required />
      <button>Add/Remove</button>
    </form>
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you would like to test a functioning version, go to the following:

- [**Example A**](https://plnkr.co/plunk/S4TemmVwWhtF7FCF)
- [**Example B**](https://plnkr.co/plunk/c3Iddrtu7rIG7dHL)